# Get SUM() of COUNT() result SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that finds the BusinessEntityID's that have 2 or more addresses - this works fine and i get 36 rows as a result, indicating that 36 businesses have two or more addresses.

```
SELECT count(BusinessEntityID) FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress
GROUP BY BusinessEntityID
HAVING COUNT(BusinessEntityID) >= 2
```

How do I modify this query so I can sum the result? I need my final result to be a count of how many results i got (36) rather than the rows themselves.

Thanks

Comment: can you please share expected result and actual result as text

Comment: please post your table structure and out of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the final count then this:

```
SELECT COUNT(count) from
(SELECT count(BusinessEntityID) AS count FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress
GROUP BY BusinessEntityID
HAVING COUNT(BusinessEntityID) >= 2) AS t
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, i couldn't quite figure out the syntax. Cheers!